# using a subquery as a value in node-postgres

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I need to perform something like this:

```
pg.query(`insert into tbl (field1, field2) values($1, $2)`, ["a", "(select id from another_table limit 1)"])
```

this causes the following error

```
error: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "(select id from another_table limit 1)"
```

Comment: The subquery must be part of the query, not of your Node-code. Rewriting the VALUES-part to use a SELECT might be cleaner: `INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2) SELECT $1, id FROM another_table LIMIT 1;`. This also fixes the other syntax error in your SQL, the comma right before `, values(`.

Comment: ok, what does the fill query look like inside `node-postgres`? @FrankHeikens

Comment: solved by `pg.query(`INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2) values ($1, $2) `, ["'a'", "SELECT $1, id FROM another_table LIMIT 1"])`

note that the subquery is not wrapped by single quoyes

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the INSERT to use a SELECT:

```
pg.query(`INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2) SELECT $1, id FROM another_table LIMIT 1;`, ["a"])
```

However, a LIMIT without an ORDER BY is rather strange and can lead to unexpected results.